# Getting an ' instance.requestPaymentMethod is not a function' in Braintree's sample

Tags: paypal, braintree

I'm getting an `instance.requestpaymentmethod is not a function` when I was just following along the tutorial for custom-field integration found here:

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/tutorial-hosted-fields-node

The error happens when I click on the "Pay" button.

Did anyone solve this problem? My assumption is that the code isn't updated or the script sources changed somewhat. If anyone from Braintree can actually help, that'll be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://help.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

I took a look at the example code snippet in [the guide you shared](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/start/tutorial-hosted-fields-node#add-the-hosted-fields-ui-markup) and I was able to find the culprit. First off, the error you're getting is expected as the `requestPaymentMethod` method actually belongs to our [Drop-In UI solution](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web-drop-in/docs/current/Dropin.html#requestPaymentMethod) and the Hosted Fields JS library doesn't have such module. I informed our Documentation team to get that code example updated.

That being said, you can find a working example in our [Hosted Fields guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/setup-and-integration#basic-integration). If you check the `function (hostedFieldsErr, hostedFieldsInstance)` callback function, you'll see that the payment nonce is created by the [`tokenize`](https://braintree.github.io/braintree-web/current/HostedFields.html#tokenize) function of the `hostedFieldsInstance`.

Comment: Thanks for that @JacqueD. On a side note, would you be able to ask as well your docs team to update the code sample in https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/paypal/client-side/javascript/v3 I just tried to copy-paste the code sample with a valid client token but I'm getting "Paypal flow property is invalid or missing". It's just a one-liner but it really saves a lot of time

Comment: There should certainly be a note there indicating that a flow of vault or checkout is required, so I'll pass that along. If you find any other errors, feel free to fill out the `Give us feedback on this page` section at the bottom of each page.

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into this issue today. Use the following code in `<script>` tag. It will work for you.

```
var form = document.querySelector('#hosted-fields-form');
var submit = document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]');

braintree.client.create({
    authorization: '<YOUR_TOKENIZATION_KEY>'
}, function (clientErr, clientInstance) {
    if (clientErr) {
        console.error(clientErr);
        return;
    }

    braintree.hostedFields.create({
        client: clientInstance,
        styles: {
            'input': {
                'font-size': '14px'
            },
            'input.invalid': {
                'color': 'red'
            },
            'input.valid': {
                'color': 'green'
            }
        },
        fields: {
            number: {
                selector: '#card-number',
                placeholder: '4111 1111 1111 1111'
            },
            cvv: {
                selector: '#cvv',
                placeholder: '123'
            },
            expirationDate: {
                selector: '#expiration-date',
                placeholder: '10/2019'
            }
        }
    }, function (hostedFieldsErr, hostedFieldsInstance) {
        if (hostedFieldsErr) {
            console.error(hostedFieldsErr);
            return;
        }

        form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            hostedFieldsInstance.tokenize(function (tokenizeErr, payload) {
                if (tokenizeErr) {
                    console.error(tokenizeErr);
                    return;
                }
                console.log('Got a nonce: ' + payload.nonce);

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<YOUR_API_URL>',
                    data: { 'paymentMethodNonce': payload.nonce }
                }).done(function (result) {
                    hostedFieldsInstance.teardown(function (teardownErr) {
                        if (teardownErr) {
                            console.error('Could not tear down Drop-in UI!');
                        } else {
                            console.info('Drop-in UI has been torn down!');
                            $('#submit-button').remove();
                        }
                    });

                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#checkout-message').html('<h1>Success</h1><p>Your Drop-in UI is working! Check your <a href="https://sandbox.braintreegateway.com/login">sandbox Control Panel</a> for your test transactions.</p><p>Refresh to try another transaction.</p>');
                    } else {
                        console.log(result);
                        $('#checkout-message').html('<h1>Error</h1><p>Check your console.</p>');
                    }
                });
            });
        }, false);
    });
});
```